# ipconfig/renew not changing the ip

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipconfig

I try to change my IP address assigned by DHCP using renew command, but it shows only the previous IP address rather than new one. Here is the command :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user>ipconfig/renew

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : <value>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : <value>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : <value>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : <value>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : <value>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

C:\Documents and Settings\user>
```

At the execution of `renew` command everytime, I get 192.168.1.16 IP address. Why it is not changing ?

Comment: Your DHCP server (probably your home router) still has the old IP in its tables linked to the network adapter MAC address so it's still going to give you the same address as the router hasn't issued it elsewhere. This is by design for efficiency. It is the DHCP server that controls what device gets what IP, not your OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explains this is small steps:

## A completely clean setup.

- Your PC sends a DHCP requests. (Basically: "Hi. I am $MACaddress here and I would like an IP address for this network")
- The DHCP server responds with "Hi $MACaddress. Please use these values. They are valid for X hours"

The PC now knowns which IP to use and how long these are valid.

After half X hours (e.g. if the DHCP lease was for 4 hours then this would trigger after 2 hours):

- PC: "Hi DHCP server, I have this information from you and I want permission to keep using it for a bit longer then I currently have rights. Can I do so?"
- DHCP server: Sure, keep using them for up to X more hours.
  So valid from a total of 6 hours after the first request: 2+4

This **renew** actions will not typically change your IP address. You just get permission to use that information for a longer period of time.

## Helpful DHCP servers.

A DHCP server usually has a small pool of addresses to hand out. Many will remember which IP address was handed out to which MAC.  After that lease expires (or if you release it, e.g. with `ipconfig /release` then the DHCP server is allowed to remember this. When the next request comes it may hand out the first free IP in its pool, or it can hand out the 'fresh' IPs which are not yet used or whose usage is the longer ago. This means that you typically get the same IP even after the lease has expired.

Comment: OK, it depends completely on dhcp ?

Comment: Yes. You are asking it "can I please have the same IP for a longer period". If the DHCP client is ancient or broken it might give you a new IP, but anything from the last 20 years probably gives you the same IP again.  If you want to change IPs, then either 1) Configure a different (static) IP. 2) Or change thereservations on the DHCP server.

Comment: In Addition: If the Client fails to contact the DHCP Server for renewal, it will continue to use that IP Address, until it reaches ~ 85% of the lease time. If it then still fails to renew the IP, it will send additional DHCP-Discovery requests and start to accept IP-Addresses from other DHCP Servers as well. If it finally fails to renew until the lease time has expired, the client takes one of two options: 1.) IF it can reach the configured default gateway, it will keep the settings and become orphaned. 2.) If the default gateway is not reachable, it will reconfigure to the range 169.254.0.0

Answer (score 1):

From a cmd/powershell prompt, try this.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

And to be honest, like the first guy explained, you may still get the same IP. If you do, there's nothing you could really do, other than running just the first command again, and then disconnecting your PC from that network for "a while". And in this case "a while" would be for how long it takes until the DHCP server grants your old IP to a new client, which could be 5 minutes, or 5 days, or longer. It's impossible to tell.

Comment: This answer duplicates what was already provided in Hennes's answer.  The intent is that each answer should provide a solution that is substantially different from what has already been contributed.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem often. I assume you have added the MAC to your router's static address table.

1. Run `ipconfig /release` on your machine
2. Physically unplug the connection to your machine
3. Reboot your router
4. Plug in your machine

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I had the same issue to get another IP address from a DHCP server. I simply reserved leased IP address and on client PC:

```
ipconfig /release 
ipconfig /renew     (sometimes, renew command 2 times).
```

You have to remember to disable reservation after getting a new IP.